# Initiating Conversation with Dialogflow, FB messenger and Python

Tags: python, facebook, dialogflow-es

I've been searching the internet and the Dialogflow docs for a solution to this but I just can't figure it out, any help to get me in the right direction is appreciated.

I'm creating a FB messenger bot and I want to use DialogFlow to handle the NLP. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to integrate DialogFlow into my Python application.

Here's my desired result:

```
Bot: You have not recorded activity for 3-4pm today, what did you do?
User: I did jogging
Bot: Added "Jogging" to your calendar from 3-4pm
```

As you can see the bot initiates the conversation, which I believe is not possible using DialogFlows FB Integration. This is why I'm looking at creating a Python bot with PyMessenger to handle the FB integration.

Is there anyway to get the entities and parameters using Python? I'm thinking something like:

```
message = "I did jogging from 2pm-5pm"
result = dialogflow.message(intent="Update Day Tracker")
print(result)
{"activity": "jogging", "time-period": "2pm-5pm"}
```

That way I could handle the majority of the logic in the Python application and just use DialogFlow to handle the NLP.

That's the only way I can think of doing this. Please let me know if there is a better solution.

I found this: https://miningbusinessdata.com/initiating-the-conversation-from-dialogflow-a-summary/ but it doesn't go into too much information

It mentions using the REST API to create your own integration - which I think is what I want to do but I've looked over the Dialogflow REST API documentation and I can't see any requests that would allow me to do what I want to do.

Any help is appreciated, if you need clarifications just let me know. Thanks for your time.

Comment: i have done this with nodejs

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya - That doesn't help much as a comment. If you've done it using another language, and can provide information about how you did it that is abstract to the language, provide an answer. If not, please don't make comments that aren't helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close! What you're looking for is using [Detect Intent in the REST API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent). This can take the text that you've gotten from the user and determine what Intent best matches it and extract the relevant parameters. It will then return the Intent that was matched, the confidence of that match, parameters associated with the match, and other information. If the fulfillment was triggered, results from the fulfillment are included.

If you're using the [python library](https://pypi.org/project/dialogflow/) for Dialogflow, the setup and call pretty closely mirrors the REST API. It might look something like this to make the call and get the response:

```
    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
        text=text, language_code=language_code)

    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

    response = session_client.detect_intent(
        session=session, query_input=query_input)
```

The response itself would match the REST [query response](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent#response-body) as well. So to get which Intent matched and the parameters for it, you might have something like

```
    intent = response.query_result.intent.display_name
    parameters = response.query_result.parameters
```